# How to create a route with an appended path on a custom post type slug in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, routes

I have a custom post type, "Job Posts", and with a slug re-write rule a single job posting can be viewed at the path `/careers/marketing_specialist`. That works well, but I would like to have a job application link on that page that would take them to `/careers/marketing_specialist/apply`. Is this possible in wordpress? I would like the path for any job application to be `/careers/{job_post}/apply`.

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at the [Rewrite Endpoints API](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/).